# Where should I put the PATH to my custom scripts folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, path

I have a folder with my handy shell scripts, called `bin`, and placed in my home:

```
/Users/<my_home>/bin
```

Every time I open a terminal (be it with the Terminal app, or with iTerm, or from VS Code, etc.), I would like to be able to launch the scripts in `bin`, without having to prefix them with the full path: so like this

```
...:~ ...$my_nifty_script.sh
```

instead of this

```
...:~ ...$/Users/<my_home>/bin/my_nifty_script.sh
```

I guess I'll have to edit the PATH environment variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<my_home>/bin
```

Where do I put this instruction, so that it gets executed every time I open a terminal?